# Ruby on Rails: formatting date inside a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My field:

```
<%= f.text_field :expires_at, :label => false, :class => "input-field" %>
```

but I want the date to be kinda like this when the page loads: June, 1st, 1752 9:54:00 pm

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a text_field for a datetime? Consider using time_select instead.

If you really want to format a date that way though, just use strftime.

So, in your case, add
`:value => @object.expires_at.strftime('%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p')`

Comment: I want the option of not having a date?

Answer (score 0):

You can format dates and times using the [strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298) method.

Answer (score 0):

See Ruby's [strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000298) and then use `:value => @date_value`

Answer (score 0):

If you want this date format to be used throughout your application, you can set the default format in your environment.rb file:

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => "%a %m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p")
```

If you do this, every time you display a date, it will be formatted according to the date format string you've provided.